# What's the ResourceId for Azure storage on national clouds?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I want to use  [`authContext.AcquireTokenAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) method to acquire an access token from Azure AD for access a storage account.

```
// Acquire an access token from Azure AD. 
    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, 
                                                                "<client-id>", 
                                                                new Uri(@"<client-redirect-uri>"), 
                                                                new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;
```

See [Authenticate with Azure Active Directory from an application for access to blobs and queues (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fqueues%2Ftoc.json).

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app#storage-resource-id), I know that the `ResourceId` is `https://storage.azure.com/` for public cloud. Are they different for national clouds?

Comment: The endpoint of the [national cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-national-cloud) is different from the public cloud, the resouceId is also.

Comment: what’s the Resouce ID for national clouds then?

Comment: Did anyone find out an answer to this?